# Are there any open-source text annotation for multi label classification tools?

Tags: deep-learning, nlp, text, annotation

I have a large texts in each document and I want to know if there are any open source text annotation tools available online for multiple label annotation.

Each sentence takes two labels. If there are any please let me know.

Comment: Can you post an example of the labels? I am wondering whether the two labels are related or if they can be seen as two separate classification problems put into one.

Comment: @Valentin Calomme They are related, I mean for example, consider text =  'my email address' and target labels are [header, personal]... another example text = "google" and target labels are [content, work].. It's for resume parsing.

Answer (score 1):

There are many manual text annotation tools available, but you will probably have to search around in order to find the one which suits your precise needs.

Here are a few pointers:

- [Gate](https://mpqa.cs.pitt.edu/annotation/gate_basics/)
- [Text annotation tools](http://www.odbms.org/2017/06/text-annotation-tools/)
- [Doccano](https://github.com/doccano/doccano)
- [a recent review](https://academic.oup.com/bib/advance-article/doi/10.1093/bib/bbz130/5670958)